# Remote ssh fails when server ip changes

Tags: server, ssh-keys, dyndns

I use Dyndns to provide a domain name to outside clients, e.g. ralph.com, so that when my provider changes my IP address, they can still access my site. This works. However, when I try to administer the server using ssh remotely, I get messages about invalid ssh key and “man in the middle” attacks. I am unable to connect to the server to correct the ssh key problem.  What can I do to either connect when this happens, or prevent this from happening?

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault, not SO, as it's not about programming specifically.

Comment: Turned out it was a “programming question” since I created an expression in a shell script to allow me to log in remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to disable the host key verification.

`ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

See here for more details : http://linuxcommando.blogspot.fr/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html

Comment: Thanks. I created an alias on my portable that uses that. I can use it when normal ssh fails. This has only happened once in several years. It allows me to log in, remove the old entry in known_hosts and then ssh again and have it work. That way I only drop strict checking for the short time I’m fixing the problem.